# Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead JSON SwiftUI

Tags: ios, json, swift, swiftui

I'm getting an error while trying to decode JSON with SwiftUI.

> typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "platforms", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "**Expected to decode Dictionary but found an array instead.**", underlyingError: nil))

I believe that it has to do with finding an empty array with platforms but I've tried to figure out how to call that information and then show it in the content view.

I think that it’s because I'm using fields in the getGames webservice, I may be messing up how I'm pulling the API. I also can't figure out where to print the JSON so I can see what is actually being pulled.

The JSON I'm trying to decode is:

```
{
    "id": 22636,
    "name": "Call of Duty: Black Ops - Annihilation",
    "platforms": [
      {
        "id": 6,
        "name": "PC (Microsoft Windows)"
      },
      {
        "id": 9,
        "name": "PlayStation 3"
      },
      {
        "id": 12,
        "name": "Xbox 360"
      }
    ]
}
```

My Game Struct Looks like:

```
Game.swift
struct Game: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let summary: String?
    let platforms: Platforms
}

struct Platforms: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String

}
```

My Webservice is using fields to get only specific parts of the API:

```
GameService.swift
public class GameService: ObservableObject {

    @Published var games = [Game]()

    init(){
        getGames()
    }

    func getGames() {

        let parameters = "fields name, summary, platforms.name; where platforms = (48,6,49); limit 10;"
        let postData = parameters.data(using: .utf8)

        let url = URL(string: "https://api-v3.igdb.com/games/")!

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.addValue("HIDDEN", forHTTPHeaderField: "user-key")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = postData

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            do {
                if let d = data {
// DO I NEED TO ADJUST THE JSONDecoder to Array<Game>.self?
                    let decodedLists = try JSONDecoder().decode([Game].self, from: d)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.games = decodedLists
                    }
                } else {
                    print("No data in response: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Unknown Error").")
                }
            } catch {
                print("\(error)")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: Platforms is an array. Just update it in this way: `let platforms: [Platforms]`

Comment: @FrancescoDeliro when I tried that i get an Xcode error says that type [Platforms] has no member 'name'

Comment: Yes because now you have to handle an array and not a single value. Where are you getting the error?

Comment: @FrancescoDeliro in the View. Text(game.platforms.name)

Comment: I answered adding an example. Let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

You’re receiving in your JSON an array of Platforms, so you have to update your Game struct to be able to parse it:

```
struct Game: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let summary: String?
    let platforms: [Platforms]
}
```

And to use it, for example:

```
List {
    ForEach(game.platforms) { platform in
        Text(platform.name)
    }
}
```

Comment: Still getting the value of type [platforms] has no member 'name'. 

```
VStack {
            List(gamesList.games) { game in
                VStack (alignment: .leading) {
                    Text(game.name)
                    if game.summary != nil {
                        Text(game.summary ?? "No Game Summary")}
                    ForEach(game.platforms) { platform in
                        Text(platform.name)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```
My observed object is gamesList that is calling the GameService()

Comment: Have you updated every place where you were using game.platforms.name?

Comment: I figured it out. My Platforms Struct enclosure wasn't inside of my Game struct. Feel free to update your answer and I'll mark it as correct. Thank you man!

Comment: You are welcome @andywalt! Nice! The answer is related with your question regarding the parsing error :) but you can edit your question showing how you handled the array after fixing the error! Thanks!